# Loading a xml file into mxml(Adobe Flex)

Tags: xml, apache-flex, adobe, loading, mxml

I have actually found this code on stackoverflow itself. I want to load an xml into mxml and then convert the loaded data into a pie chart or a bar graph.
   The code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                       creationComplete="load()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->         
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            // this is a variable definition so it is good
            var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            // these two lines are code that executes; so they must be put inside a method; something you did not do.  Comment them out 
            //xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML); // 1st error here
            //xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("books.xml")); // 2nd error here

            // this is a variable definition so it is okay
            var xmlData:XML = new XML();

            // this is a function definition so it is okay
            function loadXML(e:Event):void{             
                xmlData = new XML (e.target.data);              
            }               

            // move your executing code into a method
            public function load():void{
                xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
                xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("books.xml"));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup>      
        <s:TextArea id="txtArea">       
        </s:TextArea>               
    </s:VGroup>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

It's a code I found on stackoverflow. But still I'm not able to run the code.

And the xml file is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Books>
<Manager Man_id="1" Man_Name="P.Ananth"/>
<Manager Man_id="2" Man_Name="Gokulakrishnan"/>
<Manager Man_id="3" Man_Name="Stani"/>
</Books>
```

The error I'm incurring is this:-
Unable to locate specified base class 'spark.components.WindowedApplication' for component class 'loader2'. loader2.mxml    --    /loader2/src   --     Unknown Flex Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your project is Flex **web** project.

The `WindowedApplication` is included in the AIR SDK, meaning your project needs to be **desktop** application project.

Try,

- `<s:WindowedApplication>` to `<s:Application>`

---

**Added:**

Although the URLLoader is very important class, you may want to use HTTPService in general.

Let's take a look at code that does the same as your code above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="service.send()">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="service" resultFormat="e4x" url="books.xml"/>        
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:TextArea id="txtArea" width="100%" text="{service.lastResult}"/>       
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Isn't it simple?

URLLoader is as3 class, and the Flex framework is built on as3. HTTPService is the Flex component, which provides you easy and convenient features. It uses URLLoader internally.

Comment: Thanks for that. Although the error's gone, it shows three warnings, and it doesn't display anything on the browser.
The warnings are as follows:
(1)Multiple markers at this line:
-1084: var 'xmlLoader' will be scoped to the default namespace: loader2: internal. It will not be visible outside of this package.
-Line breakpoint: loader2.mxml [line: 15]
(2)1084: var 'xmlData' will be scoped to the default namespace: loader2: internal. It will not be visible outside of this package.
(3)1084: function 'loadXML' will be scoped to the default namespace: loader2: internal.

Comment: @Nav_cfc Let's just ignore the warnings now. Add `[Bindable]` in front of `var xmlData:XML ...` and add `text="{xmlData}"` in your `<s:TextArea>` tag. Then you will see something. Will check those warning later.

Comment: @Nav_cfc I might be away for the weekend, so I posted the final code I suggest. For those warnings, you may want to declare the scopes of the variables or methods, as `private`, `protected` or `public`. For example: `protected var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();` In ActionScript 3, specifying scope for every variable and method is highly encouraged.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked out. Just couldn't come and thank earlier!